# Error when configuring tkinter widget: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, nonetype

I am running the below code which run fine when I hard code the value

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()
with open('all_nse_stocks') as nse_stocks:
    for stock in nse_stocks:
        q = nse.get_quote('INFY')
        print q.get('open'), '\t', q.get('lastPrice'), '\t', q.get('dayHigh'), '\t', q.get('dayLow')
```

see that I have hard-coded the value nse.get_quote('INFY')
But when I run the following code, I get the following error:

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()
with open('all_nse_stocks') as nse_stocks:
    for stock in nse_stocks:
        q = nse.get_quote(stock)
        print q.get('open'), '\t', q.get('lastPrice'), '\t', q.get('dayHigh'), '\t', q.get('dayLow')
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print q.get('open'), '\t', q.get('lastPrice'), '\t', q.get('dayHigh'), '\t', q.get('dayLow')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Please help

Comment: q = nse.get_quote(stock) returns a None. Check which nse_stocks are available.

Comment: What does `all_nse_stocks` look like?

Comment: all_nse_stocks is a file which contains INFY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NoneType object has no attribute ...` means that you have an object that is `None`, and you're trying to use an attribute of that object.

In your case you're doing `q.get(...)`, so `q` must be `None`. Since `q` is the result of calling `nse.get_quote(...)`, that function must have the possibility of returning `None`. You'll need to adjust your code to account for that possibility, such as checking the result before trying to use it:

```
q = nse.get_quote(stock)
if q is not None:
    print ...
```

The root of the problem is likely in how you're reading the file. `stock` will include the newline, so you should strip that off before calling `nse.get_quote`:

```
q = nse.get_quote(stock.strip())
```

Comment: Hello Bryan, I just have only one value in all_nse_stocks i.e. INFY. If I hardcode, then I am getting the correct output. The problem is only when I read the value from file

Comment: @user3198755: have you tried _any_ debugging? For example, print out the value of `stock` before getting the quote.

Comment: Yes, after the for loop, I tried printing the stock value and it gives the correct value i.e. INFY

Comment: @user3198755: are you certain it's precisely `INFY` and not `INFY<newline>`? It probably has a newline on it which you need to strip off. I've updated my answer to show how.

Comment: I have double checked. It doesn't have any new line character at the end. nse.get_quote('INFY') works but nse.get_quote(stock) doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the single quotes? INFY and 'INFY'?

Comment: I am really not sure why but this thing helped me q = nse.get_quote(stock.strip()). Eventhough there was no newline character.

Comment: @user3198755: there could have been a space, or any other invisible character(s).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the type of 'stock' in 
q = nse.get_quote(stock)

it must be a string. Also nestools is only supported on Python2, you have not clarified about your python version.

If you are still facing the issue by the time of reading it, please let me know.